# uib-timepicker null values invalidate the form

Tags: angularjs

I am using uib-timepicker I want to validate the form to true when there is no value in textbox it return null value.
So I am setting the code manually and try to validate the form but it is not working

**HTML code**

```
<form name="myForm">
  <uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed(myForm)" hour-step="hstep" min="null" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></uib-timepicker>
  {{myForm.$invalid}}
</form>
```

**JS code**

```
 $scope.changed = function (myForm) {
    if(!$scope.mytime)
    myForm.$invalid = false;
    $log.log('Time changed to: ' + $scope.mytime);
  };
```

When there is no value in textbox it invalidate the form even if I set **myform.$invalid = false**
How can I validate form where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.changed = function () {
    if(!$scope.mytime)
    $scope.myForm.$setValidity('custom',false,window); // this will set your form validity to false
    $log.log('Time changed to: ' + $scope.mytime);
};
```